# How to Update Tensorflow from source

Tags: tensorflow

I installed the latest `Tensorflow 0.5.0` from source via git clone.
and want to update to `Tensorflow 0.6.0`

```
git pull
./configure
bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer
```

but the Tensorflow library in the directory `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` still has the version 0.5.0

the version in the result of `"pip show tensorflow"` also is `0.5.0`

Answer (score 10):

To install the TensorFlow library from source, you need to [build a PIP package and install it](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#create-pip). The steps are as follows:

```
$ git pull
$ ./configure

$ bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
# ...or, with GPU support
$ bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg

# The name of the .whl file will depend on your platform.
$ pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-0.6.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Comment: i have directory structure, serving/tensorflow. 
I installed it from source. now when I git pull in serving will it also pull tensorflow. (as in --recurse submodules.) ?

Comment: for some reason when I run the `bazel build` it isn't making a `bazel-bin` directory. the only error message I saw was this (seemingly unrelated) `ERROR: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_clone/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/BUILD:45:1: error while parsing .d file: /home/volcart/.cache/bazel/_bazel_volcart/62dff5ffffc63bcd8a9350984645e0be/execroot/tensorflow_clone/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/_objs/pyt`

Comment: Basically, to update is to re-install from source, there is no shortcut, right? Also, given it takes a while to install from source, how often it is recommended to re-install from source? Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel: It depends if you *need* to install from source (e.g. because you are using a platform for which binaries are not available). If possible, I'd recommend installing the regular releases (the most recent is TensorFlow 1.2) using `pip install tensorflow` (or `pip install tensorflow-gpu`); otherwise I'd recommend sticking to the release branches, which tend to be more reliable, because of the additional testing as part of the release process.

Comment: @mrry, thanks! Previously I insisted on install from source is intended to solve the warning message: `The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations`. Recently I have not seen these warnings at all. Does this mean either installing from source or installing with binary release such as `pip install --upgrade tensorflow-1.2.0rc1-py3-none-any.whl`, can fixed the warning message mentioned earlier?

Answer (score 1):

`git pull` doesn't work for me since some local files are modified by the last build so with a slight modification I update like this:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
./configure
bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
sudo pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-0.8.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

Tested to work as of today. The Installation from Source instructions in tensorflow docs are misleading in the sense they only include the real pip wheel installation commands for Mac and the example-trainer build command exists instead in Linux instructions.

Answer (score 1):

To show the version:

```
python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__version__);"
```

And if it is not the latest, you have uninstall it via pip uninstall:

```
sudo pip uninstall tensorflow
```

and subsequently install it:

```
export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
sudo pip install $TF_BINARY_URL
```

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to update tensorflow try updating pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

If you are upgrading from a previous installation of TensorFlow < 0.7.1, you should uninstall the previous **TensorFlow** and **protobuf** using,

```
pip uninstall
```

first to make sure you get a clean installation of the updated protobuf dependency.

Uninstall the TensorFlow on your system, and check out [Download and Setup to reinstall again](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup#download-and-setup).

If you are using pip install, go check the available version over https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow, search keywords with linux/cpu/tensorflow to see the availabilities.

Then, set the path for download and execute in sudo.

```
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-py2-none-any.whl

$ sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

For more detail, follow this link in [here](http://e-lin.github.io/wiki/jekyll/update/2017/02/18/Upgrade-the-Installed-TensorFlow.html)

If you get the error saying  **not a supported wheel on this platform**. You might be updating tensorflow for python3. For that you will need pip3
Try installing pip3

```
sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
```

Then, set the path for download if you haven't already set the path

```
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl

$ pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

Answer (score 0):

updating tensorflow install with `sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`.
I find it in the below issue,mohamed-ali's comment. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1105