# tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_secs=1)) throws unexpected keyword TypeError

Tags: python, tensorflow

As per the instructions at https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/monitors/index.html I have added a monitor to the training script as such:

```
tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(model_dir=model_dir,
                                   feature_columns=deep_columns,
                                   hidden_units=[50, 100, 50],
                                   config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(
                                            save_checkpoints_secs=1))
```

However, this throws the following TypeError:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'save_checkpoints_secs'

There are additional lines of code included related to the logging and monitoring, however they seem irrelevant to this problem...maybe...maybe not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you're running a version of tensorflow that is < `0.10`. Versions below `0.10` do not take a `save_checkpoints_secs` keyword for `RunConfig` initialization.

You should upgrade your `tensorflow` installation:

[How to Update Tensorflow from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239537/how-to-update-tensorflow-from-source)

[Download and Setup](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html)

Comment: Yes...spot on. Thank you very much.