# Update TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, upgrade

I'm working with `Ubuntu 14.04` , I had a `TensorFlow V0.10` but I want to update this version. 
if i do:

```
$ pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

but it prints:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1198, in prepare_files
    do_download,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1376, in unpack_url
    self.session,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 572, in unpack_http_url
    download_hash = _download_url(resp, link, temp_location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 433, in _download_url
    for chunk in resp_read(4096):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 421, in resp_read
    chunk_size, decode_content=False):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 225, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 174, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 573, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 341, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 260, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
SSLError: The read operation timed out

Storing debug log for failure in /home/brm17/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Could be internet problem. Try reset router / using proxy?

Comment: This is due to weak internet connection. Try setting default timeout (HTTP timeout) using 
**pip --default-timeout=100 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL**

Comment: @Kh40tiK how i do this ?

Comment: @Prabhjot : an error `You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")` !

Comment: @Brm-Covißio : You haven't set the environment variable $TF_BINARY_URL. Try doing **pip --default-timeout=100 install --upgrade tensorflow**

Comment: @Prabhjot other error : 
`Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement tensorflow in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Downloading/unpacking tensorflow
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for tensorflow in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpHw3sqs`

Comment: Try installing the package with a whl file: 


`sudo pip --default-timeout=100 install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`

Comment: an error  : 
`tensorfl‌​ow-1.0.0-cp27-none-l‌​inux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Storing debug log for failure in /home/brm17/.pip/pip.log`

Comment: @Prabhjot 
`an error : tensorfl‌​ow-1.0.0-cp27-none-l‌​inux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. Storing debug log for failure in /home/brm17/.pip/pip.log `

Comment: help me please !

Comment: `is not a supported wheel on this platform` can be caused by old versions of pip as well; did you try `pip install --upgrade pip`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Update Tensorflow from source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239537/how-to-update-tensorflow-from-source)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
(tensorflow)$ pip install --upgrade pip  # for Python 2.7
(tensorflow)$ pip3 install --upgrade pip # for Python 3.n

(tensorflow)$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow      # for Python 2.7
(tensorflow)$ pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow     # for Python 3.n
(tensorflow)$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu  # for Python 2.7 and GPU
(tensorflow)$ pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu # for Python 3.n and GPU

(tensorflow)$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==1.4.1 # for a specific version
```

Details on [install tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux).

Comment: For me upgrading tensorflow alone made tensorflow giving errors. I have to upgrade the tensorflow-gpu also to get it working

Comment: for Windows users, if you get `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` or `Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.`or similar, try updating MSVC Runtime to the latest as described in issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35749

Comment: Thank you!
The command worked for me to upgrade TF to 2.8.0 (Python 3):

pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.8.0

Answer (score 28):

To upgrade any python package, use `pip install <pkg_name> --upgrade`.

So in your case it would be `pip install tensorflow --upgrade`. Just updated to `1.1.0`

Comment: doesn't always work: No distributions at all found for tensorflow in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages

Answer (score 6):

This is official recommendation for upgrading Tensorflow.

To get TensorFlow 1.5, you can use the standard pip installation (or pip3 if you use python3)

```
$  pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

Comment: Often you have to sudo the command: sudo pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow

Answer (score 5):

**Tensorflow upgrade -Python3**

```
>> pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow --user
```

**if you got this**

> "ERROR: tensorboard 2.0.2 has requirement grpcio>=1.24.3, but you'll
>   have grpcio 1.22.0 which is incompatible."

**Upgrade grpcio**

```
>> pip3 install --upgrade grpcio --user
```

Answer (score 2):

Before trying to update tensorflow try updating pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

If you are upgrading from a previous installation of TensorFlow < 0.7.1, you should uninstall the previous **TensorFlow** and **protobuf** using,

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

to make sure you get a clean installation of the updated protobuf dependency.

Uninstall the TensorFlow on your system, and check out [Download and Setup to reinstall again](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup#download-and-setup).

If you are using pip install, go check the available version over https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow, search keywords with linux/cpu/tensorflow to see the availabilities.

Then, set the path for download and execute in sudo.

```
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-py2-none-any.whl

$ sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

For more detail, follow this link in [here](http://e-lin.github.io/wiki/jekyll/update/2017/02/18/Upgrade-the-Installed-TensorFlow.html)

Answer (score 2):

For anaconda installation, first pick a *channel* which has the latest version of tensorflow binary. Usually, the latest versions are available at the channel `conda-forge`. Then simply do:

```
conda update -f -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

This will upgrade your existing tensorflow installation to the very latest version available. As of this writing, the latest version is `1.4.0-py36_0`

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to Tensorflow 2.0 using pip.
Requires Python > 3.4 and pip >= 19.0

```
CST:~ USERX$ pip3 show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.13.1

CST:~ USERX$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.3

CST:~ USERX$ pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow

CST:~ USERX$ pip3 show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

for a specific version

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.2
```