# tensorflow .graph file doesn't generated

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

These are sample code.

```
import tensorflow as tf

const1 = tf.constant(2)
const2 = tf.constant(3)
add_op = tf.add(const1,const2)
mul_op = tf.mul(add_op,const2)

with tf.Session() as sess:

result,result2 = sess.run([mul_op,add_op])
print(result)
print(result2)

tf.train.SummaryWriter('./',sess.graph)
```

it shows message like this,

```
Tensor("Add:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

However no file generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified code, that should run:

```
import tensorflow as tf

const1 = tf.constant(2)
const2 = tf.constant(3)
add_op = tf.add(const1,const2)
mul_op = tf.multiply(add_op,const2)  # probably you use old version of TF

with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('logs', sess.graph)
    result,result2 = sess.run([mul_op,add_op])
    writer.close()
```

I removed prints, change the name of the operation to be able to run it in the new version of TF (recommend to [update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43647690/1090562)) put the writer on top and closed it properly at the end. Also change the log dir.

Now from the same directory which you used to run a script run the following command: `tensorboard --logdir=logs`. Navigate the browser and see the results.

Comment: Thanks my version was 0.10rc, so I will update version 1